# GSON custom serializer for an object with a Collection field

Tags: java, json, serialization, collections, gson

I have the following schema:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    List<Integer> sequence;
}
```

I need the Json of my `Student` object to be

```
{
    name : "Bruce"
    sequence : {
         index_0 : 5
         index_1 : 2
         index_2 : 7
         index_3 : 8
    }
}
```

[The documentation](https://github.com/google/gson) doesn't clearly say how to write a serializer for collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `TypeAdapter`, something like:

```
public static class StudentAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Student> {
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, Student student)
            throws IOException {
        if (student == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.beginObject();

        writer.name("name");
        writer.value(student.name);

        writer.name("sequence");
        writeSequence(writer, student.sequence);

        writer.endObject();
    }

    private void writeSequence(JsonWriter writer, List<Integer> seq)
            throws IOException {
        writer.beginObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < seq.size(); i++) {
            writer.name("index_" + i);
            writer.value(seq.get(i));
        }
        writer.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Student read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        // This is left blank as an exercise for the reader
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then register it with

```
GsonBuilder b = new GsonBuilder();
b.registerTypeAdapter(Student.class, new StudentAdapter());
Gson g = b.create();
```

If you run this with an example student:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.name = "John Smith";
s.sequence = ImmutableList.of(1,3,4,7); // This is a guava method
System.out.println(g.toJson(s));
```

Output:

```json
{"name":"John Smith","sequence":{"index_0":1,"index_1":3,"index_2":4,"index_3":7}}
```

Comment: //This is left blank as an exercise for the reader... nice one :) @durron597

Comment: @Kaushik well he only asked for how to serialize, not deserialize :-)

Answer (score 0):

GSON supports a custom `FieldNamingStrategy`:

```
new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingStrategy(new FieldNamingStrategy() {
    @Override
    public String translateName(java.lang.reflect.Field f) {
        // return a custom field name
    }
});
```

**But** this obviously does not cover your case, an easy workaround i can think of would be to make your `sequence` list `transient` and have an *actual* sequence map with the corrected data for GSON:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    transient List<Integer> sequenceInternal;
    Map<String, Integer> sequence;
}
```

and whenever a change occurs on your `sequenceInternal` object, write the changes through to the sequence map.